# how to pass id to jquery jtable so that it should list the entire row

Tags: php, jquery-jtable

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Prepare jTable
        $('#ListContainer').jtable({
            title: 'ITEM DETAILS',
            actions: {
                listAction: 'ListActions.php?action=list',
                createAction: 'ListActions.php?action=create',
                updateAction: 'ListActions.php?action=update',
                deleteAction: 'ListActions.php?action=delete'
            },
            fields: {
                item_id: {
                    title: 'item_id',
                    key: true,
                    list: false,
                    create: false,
                    width: '20%'
                },
                list_id: {
                    title: 'List_id',
                    width: '20%'
                },
                item_name: {
                    title: 'Item Name',
                    width: '20%'
                },
                description: {
                    title: 'Descriptions',
                    width: '20%'
                }
            }
        });

        //Load person list from server
        $('#ListContainer').jtable('load');

    });


</script>
```

this is my code..i want to pass id "listAction: 'ListActions.php?action=list'," here.. after i need to access that value in ListActions.php. how can i pass my id here?
i tried this way:
listAction: 'ListActions.php?action=list&id=$id',
here $id containing the retrieved value from database.
but this is not working.

Comment: you cant assign php variable to js with out php tags use ListActions.php?action=list&id=<?php echo $id;?> instead

Comment: thank you.. actually now the id value is passing to that page. but i cant able to access that value in ListAction .. my code is:In ListAction.php         <?php
 require_once 'DB_Interface.php';
 //echo "$id";
 if ($_GET["action"] == "list")
 {
        $db = new DB_Interface();
  $tableName = 'item_table';
  $id = $_REQUEST['$id'];
  $array_value = array();
  $array_value['list_id'] = $id;
  $primaryKey = 'list_id';
  $json = $db->getAllRecordsFromTable ($tableName, $array_value, $primaryKey);
 
  print $json;
 } ?>

Comment: i retrieved that Id by using the GET method..In ListAction.php my code is:                   $id=$_GET["id"]; its working...

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have saved your page with .php extension. So pass 'id' argument within php tags like below:

```
actions: {
                listAction: 'ListActions.php?action=list&id=<?php echo $id?>',
                createAction: 'ListActions.php?action=create',
                updateAction: 'ListActions.php?action=update',
                deleteAction: 'ListActions.php?action=delete'
            },
```

and on server side,since data is sent as GET parameters,use following:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
//Load person list from server
$('#ListContainer').jtable('load',
  {
    id1: <?php echo $_GET['id1'] ?>,
    id2: <?php echo $_GET['id2'] ?>
  }
);
```

Please mark as answer if this solution can solve your problem.